# Modifying content delivered by node-http-proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, node-http-proxy

Due to some limitations about the web services I am proxying, I have to inject some JS code so that it allows the iframe to access the parent window and perform some actions.

I have built a proxy system with node-http-proxy which works pretty nicely. However I have spent unmeasurable hours trying to modify the content (on my own, using harmon as well, etc) that is being sent to the user without any success. I have found some articles and even some questions here but all of them are outdated and are not useful anymore.

I was wondering if someone can give me an actual example about how to do this, because I am unable to do it and maybe it is just that it is impossible to do at this point?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried harmon, but I did try cheerio and it works. 
However, I used http-mitm-proxy and not node-http-proxy.

If you are using http-mitm-proxy, you need to return a promise in the response handler. Otherwise, the proxy continues to send the original response without picking up your changes.

I have recently written another proxy at:
https://github.com/noeltimothy/noelsproxy

I'm going to add response handling to this soon. This one uses a callback mechanism, which means it wont return the response until the caller signals it to.

You should be able to use 'cheerio' and alter the content in JQuery style.